# i have made a call button in android it shows fatal exception main error can any one explain this or give me another code?

Tags: android

**this is the code I use to develop my program and it shows fatal exception main error

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ImageButton call = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call);
            call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent call = new Intent
                            (Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tell:0774459581"));
                                startActivity (call);

                }
            });
```

.......
....
....

Answer (score 1):

```
  Intent call = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tell:0774459581"));
```

you misspelled `tell:`. It should be `tel:`

Remember to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

to your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ImageButton call = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call);
        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            /*
             * (non-Javadoc)
             * 
             * @see android.view.View.OnClickListener#onClick(android.view.View)
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri
                        .parse("tel:0774459581"));
                startActivity(call);
            }
        });
    }

}
```